# Invalid argument - org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException - Selenium JAVA

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument
for the below code

```java
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Chrome\\New folder\\chromedriver_win32 (3)\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://cgi-lib.berkeley.edu/ex/fup.html");
        System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
        driver.findElement(By.name("upfile")).click();

    }
```

Comment: share the entire error stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you can not trigger `.click` on that web element, resulting in error.

in case if your final goal is to upload a file, you can use the below code :

Remove this :

```
driver.findElement(By.name("upfile")).click();
```

and replace with :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[type='file']"))).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\your file loaction\\Downloads\\ASCFTR-5404.docx");
```

Comment: I will use AutoIT to select file. But problem here is i am not able to click on the "choose file" button once i opened  the URL - https://cgi-lib.berkeley.edu/ex/fup.html. can you please helm on how to  just click on that element?

Comment: AutoIT will create .exe file which you won't be able to run on cross platform. Now it's been really old but if you happen to find `input[type='file']` in entire webpage, then you can do `send_keys`, try running the above code, it would upload the file without needing to use AutoIT

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sendKeys` to pass the file path and click on the press button

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Chrome\\New folder\\chromedriver_win32 (3)\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://cgi-lib.berkeley.edu/ex/fup.html");
    System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
    driver.findElement(By.name("upfile")).sendKeys("filePath.png");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();
```

Comment: I just need to click on "Choose file "  button webElement once the   URL - "https://cgi-lib.berkeley.edu/ex/fup.html" is opened .Once I click on "choose file " it should ask for the file. thats all. Currently i am not able to click on "choose file " button and getting  org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument . Please help me on this .

Comment: @Siddesha Okay If you check the HTML source of the page you would see the `input[@type='button']` is under shadow-DOM as `shadow-root(user-agent)` and shadow-DOM is closed, And you can't take the JSPath of the element in the closed shadow-DOM